# Multiple concept-constrained parameter packs in variadic function in C++20 does not accept arguments in the first parameter pack

Tags: c++, overloading, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code uses multiple parameter packs to define a variadic template accumulator function that accepts any numeric type or pointer to numeric type:

```
// Compile with --std=c++20

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept number = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
             && !std::is_pointer_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept pointer = std::is_arithmetic_v<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>
               && std::is_pointer_v<T>;


double foo ()
{return 0;}

double foo (pointer auto     p0)
{return *p0;}

double foo (pointer auto     p0,
            pointer auto ... ps)
{return *p0 + foo (ps ...);}

double foo (number  auto     n0,
            pointer auto ... ps)
{return n0 + foo (ps ...);}

double foo (number  auto     n0,
            number  auto ... ns,  /* <---- THIS LINE */
            pointer auto ... ps)
{return n0 + foo (ns ..., ps ...);}


int main()
{
    float f = 3.;
    unsigned u = 4;
    
    foo (); // Compiles
    foo (1); // Compiles
    foo (&f); // Compiles
    foo (1, &f); // Compiles
    foo (1, &f, &u); // Compiles
    foo (&f, &u); // Compiles
    
    foo (1, 2.); // Error!
    foo (1, 2., &f); // Error!
    foo (1, 2., &f, &u); // Error!
}
```

The error triggers when there is more than one argument of type `number`.

It looks like when there are multiple parameter packs, the compiler packs all arguments in the last pack, instead of refering to the constraints to define which argument belongs to which parameter pack.

Is this a limitation of the language? Are multiple parameter packs meant to be used in some other way? Is there any workaround to make it work?

tested in clang and GCC

**Update: Solved!**

Solution: Use a single parameter pack, do not constrain the parameter pack, and constrain the type of the parameters on a one-by-one basis.

```
// Compile with --std=c++20

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept number = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept pointer = std::is_arithmetic_v<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>
               && std::is_pointer_v<T>;


double foo ()
{return 0;}

double foo (pointer auto     p0)
{return *p0;}

double foo (pointer auto     p0,
            pointer auto ... ps)
{return *p0 + foo (ps ...);}

template <typename ... N_P>
double foo (number auto n0,
            N_P ... ps)
{return n0 + foo (ps ...);}


int main()
{
    float f = 3.;
    unsigned u = 4;
    
    foo (); // Compiles
    foo (1); // Compiles
    foo (&f); // Compiles
    foo (1, &f); // Compiles
    foo (1, &f, &u); // Compiles
    foo (&f, &u); // Compiles
    
    foo (1, 2.); // Good!
    foo (1, 2., &f); // Good!
    // foo (1, &f, 2.); // Does not compile (Good!)
    return foo (1, 2., &f, &u); // Good!
}
```

Comment: A type cannot be both arithmetic and a pointer, so `std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && !std::is_pointer_v<T>` is redundant.

Comment: "*Are multiple parameter packs meant to be used in some other way?*" Broadly speaking, multiple function parameter packs are not meant to be used *at all*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deduction for function parameter packs only occurs for the *last* pack in the argument list. All other packs are [considered a non-deduced context](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#deduct.type-5):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> ...
>
> A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list.

Concepts doesn't affect this. You can't use concepts as a way to make the first pack deducible.

In any case, it's much easier to just have a concept that could be an arithmetic type or a pointer to an arithmetic type, a fold expression, and a [single function to distinguish which from which](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9W1q6d):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept number = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>; //Pointers aren't arithmetic types.

template <typename T>
concept ptr_to_num =
    std::is_pointer_v<T> &&
    number<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>;

template<typename T>
concept ptr_to_num_or_num =
    number<T> || ptr_to_num<T>;

template<ptr_to_num_or_num T>
double dereference(T p)
{
    if constexpr(ptr_to_num<T>)
        return *p;
    else
        return p;
}

template<ptr_to_num_or_num ...Args>
double foo(Args ...args)
{
    return (0.0 + ... + dereference(args));
}

int main()
{
    float f = 3.;
    unsigned u = 4;
    
    foo (); // Compiles
    foo (1); // Compiles
    foo (&f); // Compiles
    foo (1, &f); // Compiles
    foo (1, &f, &u); // Compiles
    foo (&f, &u); // Compiles
    
    foo (1, 2.); // Error!
    foo (1, 2., &f); // Error!
    foo (1, 2., &f, &u); // Error!
}
```

Yes, you will be able to pass pointers before numbers. But isn't that a better interface for whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: I must preserve order of arguments due to the semantics of the function.

Comment: I wonder why multiple deduced parameter packs does not trigger a compiler error

Comment: @Arjonais: Because the standard says that only the last one gets deduced. The others are *empty*, which is perfectly valid state for a pack.

Comment: @Arjonais: "*I must preserve order of arguments due to the semantics of the function.*" Why? If there is a specific need for this beyond personal preference, then you should use a use-case where it's actually important to be able to preserve that notion.

Comment: The actual function is a constructor that takes not two, but several parameter types. Also, it's not about arithmetic types and their pointers, but more abstract, unrelated concepts. I prepared this use-case to simplify the problem and focus on the underlying error.

Comment: Sorry, I was refering to a specific error, such as in "multiple constrained parameter packs are not allowed" rather than the confusing multi-error output. Or at least a warning "Parameter pack X is always empty because only the last constrained pack may be deduced"

Comment: @Arjonais: "*Parameter pack X is always empty*" But it's *not* always empty; you can specify the values for some of the first pack explicitly.